# Repeating a regex pattern for date parsing

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have the following string

```
"31032017"
```

and I want to use *regular expressions* in `R` to get

`"31.03.2017"`

What is the best function to do it? 
And a general question, how can I repeat the matched part, like as in `sed` in `bash`? There, we use `\1` to repeat the first matched part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the single parts in round brackets like this:

```
sub("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})", "\\1.\\2.\\3", "31032017")
```

You can then use \\1 to access the part matched by the first group, \\2 for the second and so on.

Note that if your string is a date, there are better ways to parse / reformat it than directly using regex.

Comment: Very nice, I would use `\\d` instead of `[0-9]` but that's just syntactical sugar.

Answer (score 3):

```
date_vector = c("31032017","28052017","04052022")

as.character(format(as.Date(date_vector, format = "%d%m%Y"), format = "%d.%m.%Y"))

#[1] "31.03.2017" "28.05.2017" "04.05.2022"
```

---

If you want to work/do math with dates, omit `as.character`.